# failed to roslaunch remotely on another computer

Tags: ros, roslaunch, remote-launch, ssh, multiple-machines

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to remotely launch realsense from another computer. Pinging the remote PC has no problem. I can also execute the launch file from remote computer with roscore on my current PC successfully. I tried to set up a launch file like following:

```
<launch>
    <machine name="croc3up1" address="138.25.248.87" user="croc3up1" password="croc3up1" env-loader="~/catkin_ws/src/croc3_robot/config/env.sh" default="true"/>
    <!-- just testing a simple node-->
    <node machine="croc3up1" pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="virtual_joint_broadcaster_0" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 link0 world 100" />
</launch>
```

I also tried this:

```
<include file="$(find realsense_test)/launch/realsense_test.launch" machine="croc3up1"/>
```

However I am getting the following error message:

```
... logging to /home/johnyang/.ros/log/25f83d3e-a7db-11e6-bef6-086266c7c72e/roslaunch-johnyang-ubuntu1404-7206.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://138.25.248.22 :33411/
remote[138.25.248.87-0] starting roslaunch
remote[138.25.248.87-0]: creating ssh connection to 138.25.248.87:22, user[croc3up1]
launching remote roslaunch child with command: [env ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311 ~/catkin_ws/src/croc3_robot/config/env.sh roslaunch -c 138.25.248.87-0 -u http://138.25.248.22 :33411/ --run_id 25f83d3e-a7db-11e6-bef6-086266c7c72e]
remote[138.25.248.87-0]: ssh connection created
remote[138.25.248.87-0]: [:33411/] is not a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

[138.25.248.87-0] killing on exit
remote roslaunch failed to launch: croc3up1
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

env.sh looks like following:

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME="138.25.248.87"
export ROS_IP="138.25.248.87"
. ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.sh
exec "$@"
```

It sounded like the env.sh file is executed properly and ssh connection is established correctly. However it seemed having difficulty finding the the correct launch file to execute (throwing "is not a launch file name" error). The launch file is definitely put on the 2nd PC.

If I just manually ssh into the 2nd PC and I can perform all the roslaunch straight away (since I setup source ~/catkin/devel/setup.bash in ~/.bashrc etc already).

Any clue why using the "machine" tag to remotely start launch files does not work here? (I'm using ROS Jade)
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247829/failed-to-roslaunch-remotely-on-another-computer/) by [johnyang](https://answers.ros.org/users/26493/johnyang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2016-11-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [johnyang](https://answers.ros.org/users/26493/johnyang/) on 2016-11-13**:
I found something suspicious in the terminal output.  There is a space between "http://138.25.248.22" and ":33411"... which is probably the major reason of the error. Maybe there is a bug in the source code for ROS Jade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out eventually after going through the log and source code of roslaunch. It's actually because I had "export ROS_HOSTNAME=`hostname -I`" instead of "export ROS_HOSTNAME=138.25.248.22". This will then not create that extra space behind the server uri.

---

Originally posted by [johnyang](https://answers.ros.org/users/26493/johnyang/) with karma: 66 on 2016-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-14**:
If you are going to use IPs, please consider setting `ROS_IP` instead of `ROS_HOSTNAME`. See [wiki/EnvironmentVariables - Node Environment Variables - ROS_IP/ROS_HOSTNAME](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_IP.2BAC8-ROS_HOSTNAME) for some info on those variables.

**Comment by [johnyang](https://answers.ros.org/users/26493/johnyang/) on 2016-11-15**:
That's a good point. Thanks.